# Not all row groups are identical error in qwraps2

Tags: r, qwraps2

I could not debug this error. I am just doing a simple grouping using the same command in the vignette like.

```
our_summary1 <-
  list("Miles Per Gallon" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(mpg),
            "max"       = ~ max(mpg),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(mpg)),
       "Displacement" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(disp),
            "median"    = ~ median(disp),
            "max"       = ~ max(disp),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(disp)),
       "Weight (1000 lbs)" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(wt),
            "max"       = ~ max(wt),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(wt)),
       "Forward Gears" =
       list("Three" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 3),
            "Four"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 4),
            "Five"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(gear == 5))
       )
by_cyl <- summary_table(dplyr::group_by(mtcars2, cyl_factor), our_summary1)
```

However, I get this message

```
> Error in cbind(deparse.level, ...) : Not all row groups are identical.
```

The equivalent command to this runs well on my data and looks normal to me.

```
summary_table(dplyr::group_by(mtcars2, cyl_factor)
```

But I don't really know what does this error means.

## EDIT

Please note that the example here on mtcars is from the vignette and is working 100%. I just don't know what qwrap2 means by this error. I seems certain criteria for grouped data they have.

## EDIT2

It seems that this happens when the groups do not match in sizes. Here is a reproducible example.

```
summary1 <-
  list("Time-To-event" =
       list("min"       = ~ min(x),
            "max"       = ~ max(x),
            "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(x, na_rm =F )),
       "Case Status" =
       list("Dead" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(y == 1),
            "Alive/Lost-to-follow"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(y == 0)
            )
       )

dat <-  data.frame(x =c(1:10, rep(NA, 10)) ,y =rep(c(0,1), 10) ,group = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 17)))
dat <- dplyr::group_by(dat, group)

by_cyl <- summary_table(dat, summary1)
by_cyl
```

Note that I have set na_rm = FALSE (default) as I normally one would set it to TRUE. But it seems it was not the culprit anyway.

Comment: `by_cyl <- summary_table(dplyr::group_by(mtcars2, cyl_factor), our_summary1)` works for me without any error. Not sure if I am doing something incorrectly.

Comment: @RonakShah My mistake. I am using different data. But I couldn't reproduce with different example. I think I need to stress on that

Comment: @Omar113 are there any missing values in the data set?  I'm guessing there is an issue with a row being created for a missing data value which may not exits in all the groups.  Can you provide a reproducible example with the data set you are working with?

Comment: @Peter You are right. I have some missing data, but not in the grouping column. I thought the NAs should be displayed as a way of summary!

Comment: @Omar113 - explicitly add methods for missing values to `our_surmmary1`.  That may fix the problem you've run into.  If you can provide a reproducible example I would appreciate it so I can patch the package.

Comment: @Peter Please check the edit. I have added an example

Comment: @Omar113 - thank you for the example.  I've cross posted this as a [github issue](https://github.com/dewittpe/qwraps2/issues/104) and will start working on a patch for qwraps2.

Comment: @Omar113 version 0.5.2 of qwraps2, which has been submitted to CRAN and is available from [github](https://github.com/dewittpe/qwraps2) has a patch which should fix the issue.